# Convert smartphone charger into wireless

Tags: technology, wire, cell-phone

I came across this page in facebook about life hacks and they have a video saying one can convert his smartphone charger into wireless charger. This is the [link](https://www.facebook.com/viralhacks/videos/323850991312742/?comment_id=1212403298815185&ref=notif&notif_t=comment_mention&notif_id=1476713096900905) to page. I would have followed the video if it does not say you need to cut the wires in the charger. I dont want to risk my charger so I would like to ask if this is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a joke. Doing that will not convert your charger into a wireless charger because the current in the wires of the USB cable is DC.

Comment: i see. there are other video saying the same for other mobile charger

Comment: Technically, it's more of a prank.  I've never understood what people get out of these videos -- maybe they own stock in a seller of replacement chargers...

Comment: Well, pranks are also known as "practical jokes". I also considered calling it trolling. The root of it is a perverse enjoyment of the misfortune of others.